# h1 or p margin-top sums with DIV's padding, how collapse them

Tags: html, css

I needs to put paragraph and headers inside to div with padding. But margin-top of h1/p sums with padding of div and makes h1/p positioned lower. How to avoid this? I don't need set margin-top to zero, I need padding and margin collapsing like paragraph margins.

Example, where left and top padding inside div should be equal, but they don't: https://jsfiddle.net/7trhs2vp/2/

```
<div style="padding:1em;background:silver">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

body {font-size:20px;}
h1 {margin:1em 0;}
```

Comment: [I am not seeing the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/7trhs2vp/5/)

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show us the problem.

Comment: Padding doesn't collapse. You will need to take your padding into account with your top margins. You could select the first element within a DIV with `h1:first-child, p:first-child { margin-top: 0; }`;

Comment: give ur elements border to see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove or adjust the margin or the padding. Padding does not collapse like margins do.

If your `h1` or `p` have top margins are the first child elements of the container DIV that has your padding, you can target them with the CSS pseudo selector `:first-child` to remove/adjust the margin.

In the demo below I have added borders to some elements to help visualize where margins are and are not.

```css
body,
h1,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px dotted orange;
}

.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px dashed skyblue;
}

/*
   This is applied to ANY h1 or p that is the first child
   of ANY element that is a child of a .container element.

   Place the child selector (>) between .container and/or 
   h1 and p to limit it to only child elements of .container.

  .container > h1:first-child {}
*/
.container h1:first-child,
.container p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>
   H1 Header
  </h1>
  <p>
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
  </p>
  <p>
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
    Content content content.
  </p>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stq7Lykq/).

Comment: The problem with this "hack" is that first h1 or h2 may be not the first element in div. So header right after some another text will have wrong margin-top:0.

Comment: Are you sure about your assumption? [Have you verified it?](https://jsfiddle.net/stq7Lykq/1/). I believe you are thinking of [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and not [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type).

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I have this order of tags: `P` , `H1` , `...` , `H2` on page http://www.avitasport.ru/product/Maxler-Magnesium-B6-120-tabletok.html with style applied only to `H2`, which is third in styles `#contentpadding h1:first-child, h2:first-child, h3:first-child {
  margin-top:0;
}`, strange behavior...

Comment: @copenhagen72 I think you forgot to close a `<p>`. Check `.product_cena`, it doesn't have a closing `</p>`.

Comment: Fixed (validator.w3.org almost ok), but still that style above not used for first `P` and then `H1` tags, hmmm...

Comment: What about if I add headers or paragraphs into another `DIV` of parent `DIV`? Seems like `.container h1:first-child` works not only in `.container`, but in inner `.containerSecond`  too: https://jsfiddle.net/copenhagen72/ayrv8dpu/

Comment: The current selector is `.container h1:first-child` which is applied to ANY `h1` that is the first child of ANY element that is a CHILD of `.container`. Adding the child selector `>` will bring the top margin back to your `.containerSecond` paragraph as it will force the `h1` or `p` to be a child of a `.container` element. You can take it further by creating a class specifically for applying the top margin styles. i.e. `.my-content > h1:first-child, .my-content > p:first-child {...}`. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayrv8dpu/1/) and add/remove `.my-content` from `.container-second`.